# Shell Scripting issue

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script to make an application I have developped run as a service on Linux. The shell script I wrote works perfectly when I used the  **./smpp-daemon.sh start**. However when I want to use the following syntax : **sh smpp-daemon.sh start**  I got the following error:/srv/smpp/bin/smpp-daemon.sh: 26: /srv/smpp/bin/smpp-daemon.sh: function: not found
/srv/smpp/bin/smpp-daemon.sh: 27: local: not in a function.

This is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Unity SMPP Daemon script
#
# Arsene Tochemey GANDOTE

# Set this to your Java installation
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

appNameLo="smpp"                               # application name with the first letter in lowercase
appName="SMPP"                                 # application name
osUser="root"                                    # OS user name for the service
osGroup="root"                                  # OS group name for the service
appHome="/srv/$appNameLo"                       # home directory of the service application
osUserHome="/$osUser"                           # home directory of the service user
appLogFile="/var/log/$appNameLo.log"                    # log file for StdOut/StdErr
maxShutdownTime=15                                  # maximum number of seconds to wait for the daemon to terminate normally
pidFile="/var/run/$appNameLo.pid"                   # name of PID file (PID = process ID number)
javaCommand="java"                                  # name of the Java launcher without the path
javaExe="$JAVA_HOME/bin/$javaCommand"               # file name of the Java application launcher executable
javaArgs="-jar $appHome/smsgh-smpp.jar"            # arguments for Java launcher
javaCommandLine="$javaExe $javaArgs"                # command line to start the Java service application
javaCommandLineKeyword="smsgh-smpp.jar"              # a keyword that occurs on the command line, used to detect an already running service process and to distinguish it from others

# Makes the file $1 writable by the group $osGroup.
function makeFileWritable {
   local filename="$1"
   touch $filename || return 1
   chgrp $osGroup $filename || return 1
   chmod g+w $filename || return 1
   return 0;
}

# Returns 0 if the process with PID $1 is running.
function checkProcessIsRunning {
   local pid="$1"
   if [ -z "$pid" -o "$pid" == " " ]; then return 1; fi
   if [ ! -e /proc/$pid ]; then return 1; fi
   return 0;
}

# Returns 0 if the process with PID $1 is our Java service process.
function checkProcessIsOurService {
   local pid="$1"
   if [ "$(ps -p $pid --no-headers -o comm)" != "$javaCommand" ]; then return 1; fi
   grep -q --binary -F "$javaCommandLineKeyword" /proc/$pid/cmdline
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then return 1; fi
   return 0;
}

# Returns 0 when the service is running and sets the variable $pid to the PID.
function getServicePID {
   if [ ! -f $pidFile ]; then return 1; fi
   pid="$(<$pidFile)"
   checkProcessIsRunning $pid || return 1
   checkProcessIsOurService $pid || return 1
   return 0;
}

function startServiceProcess {
   cd $appHome || return 1
   rm -f $pidFile
   makeFileWritable $pidFile || return 1
   makeFileWritable $appLogFile || return 1
   cmd="nohup $javaCommandLine >>$appLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile"
   su -m $osUser -s $SHELL -c "$cmd" || return 1
   sleep 0.1
   pid="$(<$pidFile)"
   if checkProcessIsRunning $pid; then :; else
      echo -ne "\n$appName start failed, see logfile."
      return 1
   fi
   return 0; 
}

function stopServiceProcess {
   kill $pid || return 1
   for ((i=0; i<maxShutdownTime*10; i++)); do
      checkProcessIsRunning $pid
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         rm -f $pidFile
         return 0
         fi
      sleep 0.1
      done
   echo -e "\n$appName did not terminate within $maxShutdownTime seconds, sending SIGKILL..."
   kill -s KILL $pid || return 1
   local killWaitTime=15
   for ((i=0; i<killWaitTime*10; i++)); do
      checkProcessIsRunning $pid
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
         rm -f $pidFile
         return 0
         fi
      sleep 0.1
      done
   echo "Error: $appName could not be stopped within $maxShutdownTime+$killWaitTime seconds!"
   return 1; 
}

function startService {
   getServicePID
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo -n "$appName is already running"; RETVAL=0; return 0; fi
   echo -n "Starting $appName   "
   startServiceProcess
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then RETVAL=1; echo "failed"; return 1; fi
   echo "started PID=$pid"
   RETVAL=0
   return 0; 
}

function stopService {
   getServicePID
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo -n "$appName is not running"; RETVAL=0; echo ""; return 0; fi
   echo -n "Stopping $appName   "
   stopServiceProcess
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then RETVAL=1; echo "failed"; return 1; fi
   echo "stopped PID=$pid"
   RETVAL=0
   return 0; 
}

function checkServiceStatus {
   echo -n "Checking for $appName:   "
   if getServicePID; then
  echo "running PID=$pid"
  RETVAL=0
   else
  echo "stopped"
  RETVAL=3
   fi
   return 0; 
}

function main {
   RETVAL=0
   case "$1" in
      start)                                               # starts the Java program as a Linux service
         startService
         ;;
      stop)                                                # stops the Java program service
         stopService
         ;;
      restart)                                             # stops and restarts the service
         stopService && startService
         ;;
      status)                                              # displays the service status
         checkServiceStatus
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
         exit 1
         ;;
      esac
   exit $RETVAL
}

main $1
```

Please assist because I am not shell script geek. I can only get my way around.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is twofold:

1. Bash is not `sh` on Debian, Ubuntu, etc., so Bashishms won't work when you execute your script with `sh`. Debian uses `dash` for `sh` instead.
2. The `local` keyword is not, in fact, standard POSIX sh. Dash thinks it is a function call.

Easy workaround: do not use local, make sure your variable names are unique. Sh scripting is not my forte, but from what I can tell it looks like simply removing the offending `local` keyword will do in your case.

Comment: Actually, `dash` understands `local` just fine, but the `local var=value` syntax is not supported.  Split it into `local var; var=value` and it should work with Dash.  It's still not POSIX, though.  See, however, also http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=201102#28 (specifically item #4).

Answer (score 0):

Running as `./script` uses the shell stated in the `#!` "shebang" line, or your default shell if no such line exists - the latter most likely being Bash.

Running as `sh script` overrides the default / shebang shell, and uses the Bourne shell instead - or, more likely, Bash in backward compatibility mode.

If your script uses Bash-isms (like `local`), they won't work in the second case.

You could, of course, call `bash script`...

Comment: Thank you DevSolar. I use the bash command and it worked. I also remove the local keyword.

Comment: @BigToch: Well, *if* you execute it as Bash, there is nothing wrong in *using* Bash's features. To the contrary! That would be like a C++ programm using `char[]` instead of `std::string` so it "might" be compatible with a C compiler (which it doesn't use). ;-)